# Find and rigorously prove the supremum of the set:

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

S = $\{a \in \Bbb{Z} | a < 2+1/2$}

Given that a is in the set of all integers ($\mathbb{Z}$), would the supremum of this set be equal to $(2 + 1/2)$? If so, given an upper bound of $(2 + 1/2)$, how would I prove that for an $\epsilon < (2 + 1/2)$ this couldn't possibly be an upper bound and hence $\sup(S) = (2 + 1/2)$?

Comment: Try to list the elements of $S$. Does this set have a maximum element? What happens if it does?

Comment: Well, since $a$ is an integer, we must have that sup($S$)=$2$.

Comment: "how would I prove that for an ϵ<(2+1/2) this couldn't possibly be an upper bound"  First ask yourself if you think that is even true.  Are you claiming you believe $2.49$ can not be an upper bound of $S$?  Okay,  so that the means that there is an element of $S$ that is between $2.49$ and $2\frac 12$.  Which element is that? Is there an integer that is less than $2\frac 12$ but greater than $2.49$?  There *must* be if this is the answer you can going for.

Comment: "how would I prove that for an ϵ<(2+1/2) this couldn't possibly be an upper bound"  You would prov this be proving that for any $\epsilon < 2\frac 12$ there is always an integer $k$ so that $\epsilon < k \le 2\frac 12$.  If you can prove that then, yes, $\sup S =2\frac 12$.  But ... do you *believe* that.  What if $\epsilon = 2.49 < 2\frac 12$.  Do you *really* believe that?

Answer (score 1):

The set $S$ has $2+\frac12$ as an upper bound, but $2+\frac12$ is not the supremum of $S$. For instance, 2 is an upper bound of $S$ which is strictly smaller than $2+\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can write something doesn't mean that is the must efficient way to write it.

To prove that for any $r < \sup S$ is not an upper bound you prove that for any $r < \sup S$ there *must* be an element of $s \in S$ so that $r < s \le \sup S$.

If of $\sup S = 2\frac 12$ then that means for *any* $r < 2\frac 12$ there *must* be an integer $n$ so that $r < n \le 2\frac 12$.

Is that *true*.  What if $r = 2.49$.  Is there an integer $n$ so that $2.49 < n \le 2\frac 12$?

Obviously not.  There aren't *any* integers between $2$ and $3$ so if $n$ is an integer and $n < 2\frac 12 < 3$ then $n \le 2$.  So there are no integers and therefore no elements of $S$ that are between $2$ and $2\frac 12$.  So we can't have any number between $2$ and $2\frac 12$ actually *be* the $\sup S$

Can you finish this?

Here's food for thought.  Let $S=\{$ all even primes less than $2000\}$.  So how does $\sup S$ compare to $2000$.  If we notice that $S = \{2\}$ what does that tell us.

> Claim 1:  $2$ is an upper bound of $S$.  Pf: If $s \in S$ then $s\in \mathbb Z$ and $s < 2\frac 12$.  So $s < 3$.  ANd $s\in \mathbb Z$ so it is not true that $2 < s <3$.  And as $s < 3$ and it is not true that $s < $ and $s > 2$ it must not be true that $s > 2$. So $s \le 2$.  So $2$ is an upper bound of $S$.
>
>  Claim 2: If $r < 2$ then $r$ is not an upper bound. Pf: $2\in \mathbb Z$.  And $2< 2\frac 12$.  So $2 \in S$.  So $r < 2\in \mathbb S$.  So $r$ is not an upper bound.....